# Javascript Parent Node does not contain Child Node

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to build a flexible system that updates all childs automatically if the data model changes.

```
Label: function(parent, dataWrapper) {

    if (!(dataWrapper instanceof Ui.Wrapper.LabelData))
        throw new Error("Data element is not a instance of Ui.Wrapper.LabelData"); 

    const htmlElement = document.createElement("div");
    const self = this;

    this.update = function() {
        htmlElement.innerText = dataWrapper.label();            
    };
    this.delete = function() {
        parent.removeChild(htmlElement);
    };

    this.update();
    parent.appendChild(htmlElement);
},

...

const tasks = [];
const htmlNode = document.getElementById("wrapper");

const buttonAdd = new Ui.Static.Button(document.getElementById("buttons"), "Add", function() {
    
    ...

    uiLabelElement = new Ui.Label(htmlNode, dataWrapper);
    tasks.push(task);
    ...
});

const buttonRemove = new Ui.Static.Button(document.getElementById("buttons"), "Remove", function() {
    if (tasks.length < 1) return;
    tasks[tasks.length - 1].delete();
    tasks.splice(tasks.length - 2, 1);
});
```

The above shown script adds two buttons to the DOM.
Clicking add adds a `Ui.Label` instance to the DOM. Clicking remove shall remove the last element from the DOM.

Adding instances works as expected, but removing instances by calling `elem.delete()` will only remove the element which was added last. For any other element a `DOMException` (Node.removeChild: The node to be removed is not a child of this node) is thrown.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lju3v81k/)

Inside the label, `htmlElement.parentNode` is returing `null`. `parent` is still a vaild refernce to the actual parent, but it does not containe the `htmlElement`.

What is the reason, that the parent node does not contain the instance anymore?